# H2 does not allow to execute select with join inside set

Tags: sql, left-join, h2

I want to fill all columns in one table basing on columns from select with left join from two others:

```
update TAB1 as P
  set P.COL1 = (
  select CODE from (
  select * from TAB2 as A left outer join TAB3 as T on A.TAGID = T.ID
) as O
where P.ACTID = O.ACTID
);
```

It works properly on Oracle, but when i want to execute it on h2 I got this error:

> Duplicate column name "ID"; SQL statement

I dont know where is a problem. I could'nt find any solution for that.
Thx for the answers

Comment: You need to provide a complete test case with definitions of your `TAB1`, `TAB2`, and `TAB3` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is your problem:

```
(select * from TAB2 as A left outer join TAB3 as T on A.TAGID = T.ID)
```

Presumably, you have an `ID` in both tables, so the `SELECT *` returns two columns named `ID`.  I'm surprised this works in Oracle -- but perhaps Oracle optimizes the code because the `ID`s are not needed.

Just return the value you want:

```
(select ?.CODE from TAB2 as A left outer join TAB3 as T on A.TAGID = T.ID)
```

The question mark is either `A` or `T`, depending on which table the value comes from.

Comment: H2 and many other DBMS also allow duplicate column names in select expressions.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov . . . There is a difference between duplicate column names in a `select` versus in a subquery.  A subquery needs to know what columns are being returned to the outer query.